# Solving a simple differential equation and trying to plot the trace of the solutions

Tags: differential-equations, manipulate

I am trying to run a simple code on Mathematica. However, it is not running for some reason. What mistake am I making?

```
ClearAll {x, y, z, t, X, Y, a, b, c};
Manipulate[
  X[t_] := a Cos[t];
  Y[t_] := Sin[t];
  sols =
    {NDSolve[
      {D[{u[t], v[t]}, t] == D[{{X[t], Y[t]}, {Y[t], -X[t]}}, t].{u[t], v[t]}, 
       {u[0], v[0]} == {1, 0}}, 
      {u[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, 10}],
     NDSolve[
       {D[{u[t], v[t]}, t] == D[{{X[t], Y[t]}, {Y[t], -X[t]}}, t].{u[t], v[t]}, 
        {u[0], v[0]} == {0, 1}}, 
       {u[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, 10}][[1]]};
  GraphicsRow[{
    ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{u[t], v[t]} /. sols], {t, 0, 10}],
    Plot[Tr[{u[t], v[t]} /. sols], {t, 0, 10}]}]
  {{a, 2}, 1, 5}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You might find [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html) a convenient alternative:

```
ClearAll[pndsv, X, Y]
X[t_] := a Cos[t]
Y[t_] := Sin[t]
pndsv = ParametricNDSolveValue[
  {D[{u1[t], v1[t]}, t] == D[{{X[t], Y[t]}, {Y[t], -X[t]}}, t].{u1[t], v1[t]}, 
   {u1[0], v1[0], u2[0],  v2[0]} == {1, 0, 0, 1}, 
   D[{u2[t], v2[t]}, t] == D[{{X[t], Y[t]}, {Y[t], -X[t]}}, t].{u2[t], v2[t]}},
  {u1, v1, u2, v2}, {t, 0, 10}, {a}];


Manipulate[Row[{ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Partition[Through[pndsv[a] @ t], 2]], 
      {t, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, PlotRange -> All, 
      ImageSize -> Medium, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> False, Frame -> True], 
    Plot[Evaluate[Tr @ Partition[Through[pndsv[a] @ t], 2]], {t, 0, 10}, 
     PlotStyle -> Orange, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Medium, 
     AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]}, 
   Spacer[10]], 
{a, 1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is there's a comma missing right before `{{a, 2}, 1, 5}]` at the bottom. When I fix that, it tells me that it's trying to take the trace of a non-rectangular matrix. When I extract just the trace portion, it looks like you're trying to take the trace of an interpolating function. Are you trying to add the first interpolating function of u[t] to the second of v[t]? If so, you need to arrange `{u[t], v[t]}/.sols` into a 2 x 2 matrix, rather than `{{1}, 2}, {{3}, 4}` which is what I'm seeing. I'm not sure if the number of solutions you get might change, but I'm assuming they'll all be square matrices. If that's the case, then this should work for you:

```
Manipulate[
  X[t_] := a Cos[t];
  Y[t_] := Sin[t];
  sols = {NDSolve[{D[{u[t], v[t]}, t] == 
      D[{{X[t], Y[t]}, {Y[t], -X[t]}}, t].{u[t], v[t]}, {u[0], 
       v[0]} == {1, 0}}, {u[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, 10}], 
   NDSolve[{D[{u[t], v[t]}, t] == 
       D[{{X[t], Y[t]}, {Y[t], -X[t]}}, t].{u[t], v[t]}, {u[0], 
        v[0]} == {0, 1}}, {u[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, 10}][[1]]};
  GraphicsRow[{
    ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{u[t], v[t]} /. sols], {t, 0, 10}], 
    Plot[
      Tr[Partition[#, Sqrt[Length[#]]] &@ Flatten[{u[t], v[t]} /. sols]], 
      {t, 0, 10}
    ]
  }], 
  {{a, 2}, 1, 5}
]
```